# How to access local Docker storage on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, windows

Where does Docker daemon store image and container data on the local disk ?

Comment: `docker system info` and see "Docker Root Dir" value maybe ? (just a guess)

Comment: `Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker` it says

Answer (score 1):

Most of the persisted data is written to:
`C:\ProgramData\docker`

you should have directories here such as:

```
.\windowsfilter 
.\volumes 
.\config 
.\image
```

etc

The layer and image data is stored under these.

Comment: could you provide some examples that reside in this folder? Only service.txt exists in my case

Comment: you could update the answer